# Why is one CSS animation working Multiple Times, Another Only Once Per Pageload

Tags: javascript, css

Really stumped by this one... two animations, same structure basically, and the JavaScript
for them also the same, but one animation, will work as often as one wants to hover over
it and the other, works exactly one time on hovering, then goes away until the page is
manually refreshed.

Prepared a JSfiddle [all prettied up](http://jsfiddle.net/MountainMan72/HVH6K/41/)
and if anyone wishes, the codeblock below is complete and ready to run if you
have your stack ready for testing; it would be ready to copy and paste and runs to
illustrate the problem.

Summary: why does the red opaque expanding div animation only run once?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

    <Head>
        <Title>Bleu Goat F</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" ; content="text/html  application/pdf  text/plain text/css text/php; charset=utf-8"
        ;>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Some Name CSS FuddleDuddle.css"
        />
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var el = document.getElementById("el");
                var button = document.getElementById("button");
                el.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function (evt) {
                    el.className = "hidden";
                }, false);
                el.addEventListener("mouseover", function (evt) {
                    el.className = (window.WebKitAnimationEvent) ? "hiding" : "hidden";
                }, false);
                button.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function (evt) {
                    button.className = "bottomFADED";
                }, false);
                button.addEventListener("mouseover", function (evt) {
                    button.className = (window.WebKitAnimationEvent) ? "expandDown" : "bottomFADED";
                }, false);
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* 6:05 PM Monday, January 07, 2013
          Animation code for teal color *div el*
          Animation code for mouseover/reveal div *button* */
            #el {
                position:absolute;
                top:7px;
                left:17px;
                width:153px;
                height:32px;
                background-color:teal;
                border:1px solid white;
                font-size:17px;
                font-family:palatino linotype;
                display:block;
                cursor: pointer;
                z-index:160;
            }
            div.hiding {
                -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
                -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
                -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
                -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
            }
            div.hidden {
                display: none;
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
                from {
                    background-color:yellow;
                    opacity: .3;
                }
                to {
                    background-color:teal;
                    opacity: .9;
                }
            }
            /* *************************************** */
            /* Codeblock For Div Which **Should** become
         visible upon hovering over Name there on the
         Menu bar, and animate, increasing in size
         downward and becomeing more opaque (redder)
         then stopping, then finishing the animation and
         disappearing.
          */
            @-webkit-keyframes slidein {
                from {
                    background-color:transparent;
                    width:62px;
                    height:25px;
                }
                to {
                    background-color:red;
                    opacity: 0.6;
                    width:62px;
                    height:73px;
                }
            }
            #button {
                position:absolute;
                top:7px;
                left:149px;
                width:62px;
                height:25px;
                display: block;
                z-index:100;
            }
            #button.bottomFADED {
                display:none;
            }
            #button.expandDown {
                -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
                -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
                -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
                -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-in-out, background-color 2s, width 2s, margin 2s, color 2s, font-size 2s, z-index 1s;
                position: absolute;
                top:7px;
            }
            /* Below: the simple CSS transition on a div;
           it is in the red square below *Name* item on
           the brown Menu Bar.
           It is triggered by a :hover.  Not an animation,
           and works reliably.
          */
            #BlackAsHeidizHeart {
                position:absolute;
                top:32px;
                left:107;
                width:62px;
                height:48px;
                border:1px solid red;
                z-index:100;
            }
            #suresureBOSS22 div {
                position:absolute;
                top:32px;
                left:164px;
                width:53px;
                height:43px;
                background-color:transparent;
                color:#30000C;
                border:1 solid transparent;
                z-index:12;
                font-family:French Script MT;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-style:oblique;
                font-size:0px;
                z-index:55;
                -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-in-out, background-color 2s, width 2s, font-size 1s, border .3s;
                -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.230, 0.735, 0.845);
            }
            #suresureBOSS22 div:hover {
                position:absolute;
                top:32px;
                left:164px;
                width:151px;
                height:47px;
                background-color:green;
                color:#30000C;
                border:2px solid white;
                z-index:12;
                font-family:French Script MT;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-style:oblique;
                font-size:15px;
                z-index:55;
                -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-in-out, background-color 2s, width 2s, font-size 1s, border 3s;
                -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.230, 0.735, 0.845);
            }
            /* ************************* */
            /*  The uninteresting page~stuff */
            /* body */
            #VerdadSIxCorpusZsestyJa {
                background-color:#A9D4B6;
                color:black;
                font- size:12px;
                color:black;
            }
            /* main div */
            #BigPicturesScreen {
                position:absolute;
                top:3px;
                left:3px;
                width:97%;
                height:273px;
                background-color: #112299;
                color:black;
                border-top-color: rgb(198, 132, 19);
                border-top-style: inset;
                border-top-width: 3px;
                border-right-color: rgb(198, 132, 19);
                border-right-style: inset;
                border-right-width: 3px;
                border-bottom-color: rgb(198, 132, 19);
                border-bottom-style: inset;
                border-bottom-width: 3px;
                border-left-color: rgb(198, 132, 19);
                border-left-style: inset;
                border-left-width: 3px;
                font-size:31px;
                font-family:bookman old style;
                font-style:normal;
                z-index:2;
            }
            /* top outter div */
            #SequesterJSFiddleCODE {
                position:absolute;
                top:47px;
                left:19px;
                width:200px;
                height:53px;
                background-color:#8DA57C;
                border:2px solid forestgreen;
                font-size:17px;
                font-family:tahoma;
                z-index:140;
            }
            /* grey div with green border, holds MenuBar */
            #CODExSnippetNumberSupport {
                position:absolute;
                top:173px;
                left:5px;
                width:273px;
                height:74px;
                background-color:lightgrey;
                border:3px solid forestgreen;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
                font-size:11px;
                font-family:tahoma;
                padding-top:3px;
                padding-right:0;
                padding-bottom:3px;
                padding-left:12px;
                z-index:10;
            }
            /* the lower, Menue Bar, dark brown */
            #TitleOfTitleThingyie {
                position:absolute;
                top:3px;
                left:16px;
                width:237px;
                height:19px;
                background-color:#30000C;
                color:white;
                border:4px solid #AFEF23;
                -webkit-border-radius: 1.2em 1.2em 1.2em 1.2em;
                font-size:14px;
                font-family:bookman old style;
                padding-top:3px;
                padding-right:0;
                padding-bottom:3px;
                padding-left:12px;
                z-index:15;
            }
            /* the div holding that 7, on Menu Bar  */
            #JobCrrnt {
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:79px;
                width:29px;
                height:19px;
                background-color:#30000C;
                color:white;
                border:none;
                font-size:14px;
                font-family:bookman old style;
                padding-top:3px;
                padding-right:0;
                padding-bottom:3px;
                padding-left:12px;
                z-index:15;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body id="VerdadSIxCorpusZsestyJa">
        <div id="BigPicturesScreen">
            <div id="SequesterJSFiddleCODE">
                <br />
                <div id="el">Hide Me &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp*div el*</div>
                <!-- el -->
            </div>
            <!-- SequesterJSFiddleCODE -->
            <div id="CODExSnippetNumberSupport">
                <div id="Shellnum1" class="hover">
                    <div id="suresureBOSS22" class="hover">
                        <div id="BlackAsHeidizHeart" class="hover">Why Must WE, Suffer?
                            <br />HA! why not :)</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- suresureBOSS22 -->
                    <a href="#" id="button" style="text-decoration:none;" class="hover"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- Shellnum1 -->
                <div id="TitleOfTitleThingyie">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Job #
                    <div id="JobCrrnt">&nbsp&nbsp 7</div>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Name</div>
                <!-- TitleOfTitleThingyie -->
            </div>
            <!-- CODExSnippetNumberSupport -->
        </div>
        <!-- BigPictureScreen -->

        <body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works fine on my Chrome 23...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-webkit-animation:slidein 5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

you dont have to hide (add display:none) after animation end 
[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVH6K/49/)

Comment: @ Arun Killu Hey, um... see above, Cheers.

Comment: i saw your comment, an it seems that your code is working fine .why are you adding display:none css on animation end?????

Comment: For the reason that if the cursor is in the area defined by the thin red outlined square, then when the animation ends, the next thing that happens is the green div begins it transition immediately since hover is on... I know, it is awkward and I still have not decided on how to tempt the user or coax, them to move their cursor down into the downward expanding red opaque div; but need to get that working properly before I move on to the next part of the design.  If you were testing the hovering over the word *Name* on the title bar, you would have confirmed it is not working but once.

Comment: Yes. I visited it. Cycling on a bicycle is great, but cycling on an infinite loop after mouseout is crappy. – However, the fiddle you provided a link to, is EXACTLY the behaviour I was striving for.  Something about not using display:none.  Funny, it killed the red div, but not the teal div above.  I am accepting your answer, it works, I'll try to learn why the difference.  Cheers.

Comment: So the best I can come up with is a conjecture that whereas *button* is not a  **real** div, the div *el* is such, and is therefore made visible by css covering it even when a css class is inactive.  But using display:none on the *button* div removes it from the DOM. Which is why the use of *display : none * was fatal for one and not the other.  I love Stack Overflow and HATE CSS. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for that is -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

Replace with:

```
#button.expandDown {
                -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
                -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
                -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
                -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-in-out, background-color 2s, width 2s, margin 2s, color 2s, font-size 2s, z-index 1s;
                position: absolute;
                top:7px;
            }
```

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/HVH6K/44/

Comment: @ Munish Poonia Thanks, but a definite NOT Desired Behaviour.  The user hovering over the *Name* should trigger the animation, not to have the animation on a loop.  It is a GUI I am trying to design.  Cheers.